# Unable to select a option using select in RSpec/Capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec

Hi I'm fairly new to using Ruby/Capybara and RSPEC...I'm trying to select the month from a dropdown selectbox with value like the following

```
<legend> Expiration Date </legend>
</div>
<ul>
<li class="select input required"
    id="cart_driver_attributes_credit_card_attributes_exp_month_input">
    <select autocomplete="off" class="required select-box expiration-date"
        id="cart_driver_attributes_credit_card_attributes_exp_month"
        name="cart[driver_attributes][credit_card_attributes][exp_month]">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="02">February</option>
        <option value="03">March</option>
        <option value="04">April</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option>
        <option value="08">August</option>
        <option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
```

========================================================================

I'm using the following to select the month

```
select "August", :from => "select"
```

I tried several ways to select a month, but I keep getting `Capybara::ElementNotFound:`

Answer (score 1):

The `:from` option accepts id, name or label of the select ([documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method)). So in your case:

```
select "August", :from => "cart_driver_attributes_credit_card_attributes_exp_month"
```